# Send data by post from AngularJs to Django

Tags: angularjs, django

I want to send data from AngularJS to the back end (Django) via Http request.

I tried many ways but I keep not getting the sent data when receiving the request in django.

Before I paste my code, I just have changed the configurations in AngularJS in my project as the following

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).config(['$httpProvider', '$interpolateProvider', function ($httpProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{/');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('/}');
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';}]);
```

### The urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^save_comment/', views.save_comment, name='save_comment'),]
```

### Sending Https POST in Angular:

```
$scope.submit_comment = function () {

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'save_comment',
        data: $.param({
            'fish_id' : "1"
        })
    }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response.result);
    }).error(function () {
        console.log("failed")
    }); }
```

### Receiving the request in the Views

```
def save_comment(request):

    data = request.POST.get('fish_id')
    return JsonResponse({'result': data}, content_type="application/json", safe=False)
```

But I didn't get any result. the console gave me this error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/brain_browser/save_comment 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

So what should I do to send Post data from Angular to Django?

Thank in a dvance.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but you can debug yourself. Add this to `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `url: 'save_comment'` seems to be missing a slash at the beginning, since your url expects `http://127.0.0.1:8000/save_comment/` but because of the missing slash you are sending `http://127.0.0.1:8000/brain_browser/save_comment`.

So change the `url` in your Javascript to `url: '/save_comment/'`

Edit: @bobleujr's answer could also fix the problem if csrf tokens are the problem. In my personal Angular/Django project I simply put this at the very top of my javascript:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

2nd Edit: This should be the solution

In your views, do this instead of `data = request.POST.get('fish_id')`:

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(body_unicode)
# Work with "data" from now on, i.e:
print(data["fish_id"])
```

This is because request.body (Your parameters) is a byte string, and json.loads does not accept byte strings.

Also make sure you have `json` imported in your views at the very top like so:

```
import json
```

Comment: aslo I added $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
and didn'r work.

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar Does your server show any error? Is there a traceback which shows on which line the error occurs? You can also put `print("TEST")` in your save_comment view to see if it even triggers. The print will output in your server console.

Comment: I don't have error now just I can't get the data .. the data in console is null :( I put it in the view like this  data = request.POST.get('fish_id') but the data in the console is null :(

Comment: also didn't work :( it entered to the error function and gave me faild

Comment: it is very big I put it in the text file you can see it here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9z4jqawxzzsl51d/error.txt?dl=0

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar Your views are most likely importing the wrong json, you can test this by putting print(json.__file__) anywhere in your views and seeing what comes out. For example mine outputs `.../python3.4/json/__init__py`. You are also using Windows, which might have some effects. You might also have another file named `json` which python detects and accidentally imports.

Comment: it gave me this C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.pyc

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar I have no idea what the problem is then, sorry. You might want to post another question to figure how to get json to work and then come back here and try the solution again.

Comment: I tried to do like this in the view data = request.body but the data received as a string like this fishid=1

Comment: it worked :D I just removed the $.param from https :D